# regarding CSRF Filter in Tomcat 7 url encoding

Tags: filter, tomcat7, csrf, url-encoding

I work on a web application that is vulnerable to CSRF(Cross Site Request Forgery) attack. Tomcat 7 has a CSRF prevention filter. I went through the description to configure this filter.
This filter expects that we call HttpServletResponse#encodeRedirectURL(String) or HttpServletResponse#encodeURL(String).

However, I see that in my application we are not using the above mentioned methods. We forward the response using mapping.findForward(target); without touching the request or response object.  Can you please let me know how or where can I integrate encodeURL() or encodeRedirectURL() methods in my code?

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can Write a Servlet and map all urls (/*) to this servlet in your web.xml file. now you can use encodeUrl method through HttpServletResponse.